# Drawing phase plane with mfpic4ode

Tags: errors

I'm trying to draw a phase portrait with `mfpic4ode` and getting problems with it. I'm not sure it is installing properly. I tried installing it with MikTex package manager as admin and non-admin. When I try to build the [demo.tex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mfpic4ode) that comes with `mfpic4ode` I get:

```
! I can't find file `mfpic4ode.tex'.<to be read again>\relax \input mfpic4ode.tex\relax
! Emergency stop.<to be read again>\relax \input mfpic4ode.tex\relax
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The errors are coming from `\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\mfpic4ode\mfpic4ode.sty`

When I open that I see:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mfpic4ode}
    [2009/04/15 v0.3 mfpic4ode.dtx  file]
\input mfpic4ode.tex\relax
\endinput
```

I looked in the directory where the style document is, and I do not see `mfpic4ode.tex`.

Comment: It is indeed not properly installed: `mfpic4ode.tex` should have been there too. Is it possible to ask MikTeX to download this peculiar file and install it besides `mfpic4ode.sty`? I don't use MikTeX myself.